# What CBUUID is needed for bluetooth retrieveConnectedPeripherals swift

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get the list of services from a bluetooth peripheral that my iOS device has connected to. Is retrieveConnectedPeripherals the way to do this? If so what CBUUID do I need for it to retrieve a peripheral with a handsfree service.

```
import CoreBluetooth
class TopVC: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {    

var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var peripheral: CBPeripheral!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
 }

 // required protocol method
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        self.centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID])
    } else {
        print("bluetooth not available")
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: No, you would use `discoverServicess` on the connected peripheral, but a handsfree device is legacy Bluetooth, so you cannot discover it wit Core Bluetooth anyway

Answer (score 3):

Usually you could start with [`func scanForPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]? = nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipherals) to scan the available BT devices. Then you will have your delegate called when new devices found.

[`func retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]) -> [CBPeripheral]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals) instantly gives you a list of **currently** connected BT devices, which could not tell you what has been connected before. Generally you could pass an empty array, which would help you fetch all the connected devices.

#### How to create an `CBUUID` instance?

```
 /*!
 * @method UUIDWithString:
 *
 *  @discussion
 *      Creates a CBUUID with a 16-bit, 32-bit, or 128-bit UUID string representation.
 *      The expected format for 128-bit UUIDs is a string punctuated by hyphens, for example 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067.
 *
 */
public /*not inherited*/ init(string theString: String)
```

`let uuid = CBUUID(string: "XXXXXXX")`

Generally, if you retrieve connected peripherals with empty array of `CBUUID`, you will retrieve empty list of connected peripherals. This is caused by security reason. So you have to specify some `CBUUID` to retrieve peripherals with specified `CBService`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to Swift. Actually it should not make much difference.

Comment: hi - Xcode gives error - cannot convert [CBUUID]?.Type to expected argument type [CBUUID]?. Are you declaring this array somewhere? I am calling it in self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]?) rather than its own function. Is that what you mean?

Comment: if you have scanForPeripherals as its own function how do you call it?

Comment: `CBUUID` is a TYPE, you can place a type there, you need a instance of `CBUUID`, which could be created or retrieved from `CBService`